# Community Nav Menu - Community Page

Tags: community, napili

I'm trying to edit the standard Nav Menu component in the Napili template. I am using 'Community Page' but then I'm prompted to enter a URL string. This field pre-populates with something but I can't save it with just that. What should I be entering into this URL field?

For example, if I wanted a Nav Menu item to take a user to their User Profile page, what would I enter in this URL field?

Attached is a screenshot of the menu in question and the error I get when trying to save with the value that's pre-populated.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this isn't possible. Instead you would need to provide a hardcoded ID. Similar questions here >
[Napili Navigation Menu](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/166331/napili-navigation-menu?rq=1)

[Relentless error message for URL parameters when referencing Napili Standard Community Page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/169044/relentless-error-message-for-url-parameters-when-referencing-napili-standard-com?noredirect=1&lq=1)